# how to access numpy legendre polynomial basis functions

Tags: python, numpy, polynomials

I can't figure out how to access the Legendre basis functions L_i(x) with `numpy.polynomial.legendre`. I can only access weighted sums of them, of the sum c_i L_i where c are constant coefficients. How can I access the underlying basis functions? I must be missing something. I include a simple example of the problem below. I hand-coded the [correct polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Rodrigues'_formula_and_other_explicit_formulas) and compare them to what I am accessing with Numpy. Clearly, the weighted sum is not the desired individual basis function. How can I make the top plot match the bottom using numpy's polynomial module?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, ax = plt.subplots(2)
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)
def correct_legs(x, c):
   if c == 0: return(np.ones(len(x)))
   if c == 1: return(x)
   if c == 2: return(0.5 * (3 * x ** 2 - 1))
   if c == 3: return(0.5 * (5 * x ** 3 - 3 * x))
   if c == 4: return((1. / 8.) * (35 * x ** 4 - 30 * x ** 2 + 3))
   if c > 4 or c < 0 or type(c)!=int: return(np.nan)
for order in range(5):
   # Attempt to generate legendre polynomials with numpy
   ax[0].plot(x, np.polynomial.legendre.legval(x, np.ones(order + 1)), label=order)

   # plot propper legendre polynomials
   ax[1].plot(x, correct_legs(x, order))
ax[0].legend()
plt.savefig('simpleExample')
```

[image]

Comment: Use `c = [1]` for L0, `c = [0, 1]` for L1, `c = [0, 0, 1]` for L2, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course the desired solution depends on how you wish to use the polynomial. For the purpose of 'plotting' you can have a look at the Legendre series class. It can generate basis functions in the desired domain through the [Legendre.basis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.legendre.Legendre.basis.html) method.

For plotting it works OK

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for order in range(5):
   # Attempt to generate legendre polynomials with numpy
   x, y = np.polynomial.legendre.Legendre.basis(order, [-1, 1]).linspace(100)
   plt.plot(x, y, label=order)

plt.legend()
plt.plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a way to do it.

```
from numpy import cos, arange, pi
from scipy.special import legendre
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def P(l,chi ) :
  polynom = legendre(l)
  return polynom(chi)


CHI = arange(-1,1, 0.01)

plt.plot(CHI, P(1,CHI), lw=2, ls = '-', color = 'k')
plt.plot(CHI, P(2,CHI), lw=2, ls = '--', color = 'g')
plt.plot(CHI, P(3,CHI), lw=2, ls = '-.', color = 'b')
plt.plot(CHI, P(4,CHI), lw=2, ls = ':', color = 'r')

plt.legend(['$P_1(\chi)$','$P_2(\chi)$','$P_3(\chi)$','$P_4(\chi)$'])
plt.title(' Polynômes de Legendre ')
plt.xlabel(' $\chi = \cos\phi$ ')
plt.ylabel(' $P_l(\chi)$ ')
```

this is the output
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXGXV.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).